# Generator function in LSTM Keras for outputting mini batches of one files

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras, mini-batch

I have a generator function which works fine. I have a large list of .txt files in which each file is also quite long. The task would now be to write a generator function which Takes:

1. a batch of Files
2. and then a batch of size 128 out of one file

my code now:

```
data_files_generator <- function(train_set) {

  files <- train_set
  next_file <- 0

  function() {

    # move to the next file (note the <<- assignment operator)
    next_file <<- next_file + 1

    # if we've exhausted all of the files then start again at the
    # beginning of the list (keras generators need to yield
    # data infinitely -- termination is controlled by the epochs
    # and steps_per_epoch arguments to fit_generator())
    if (next_file > length(files))
    {next_file <<- 1}

    # determine the file name
    file <- files[[next_file]]

    text <- read_lines(paste(data_dir, file, sep = "" )) %>%
      str_to_lower() %>%
      str_c(collapse = "\n") %>%
      removeNumbers() %>%
      tokenize_characters(strip_non_alphanum = FALSE, simplify = TRUE)

    text <- text[text %in% chars]

    dataset <- map(
      seq(1, length(text) - maxlen - 1, by = 3), 
      ~list(sentece = text[.x:(.x + maxlen - 1)], next_char = text[.x + maxlen])
    )

    dataset <- transpose(dataset)

    # Vectorization
    x <- array(0, dim = c(length(dataset$sentece), maxlen, length(chars)))
    y <- array(0, dim = c(length(dataset$sentece), length(chars)))

    for(i in 1:length(dataset$sentece)){

      x[i,,] <- sapply(chars, function(x){
        as.integer(x == dataset$sentece[[i]])
      })

      y[i,] <- as.integer(chars == dataset$next_char[[i]])

    }
    rounded_dim <- floor(dim(x)[1]/mini_batch_size)
    match_size_to_batch <- 128 * rounded_dim

    x <- x[1:match_size_to_batch, 1:maxlen, 1:length(chars)]
    y <- y_val[1:match_size_to_batch, 1:length(chars)]

    return(list(x, y))

  }
}
```

So what is coming is coming in is a Text file which is transformed into smaller pieces of text (of length `maxlen`) and is then one hot encoded into 0 and 1 matrices.

The problem is that from my code the output is one Data Cube of size `maxlen x lenght(chars) x samples` where the number of samples is very big and that why I would like my generator function to output always a cube of size `maxlen x lenght(chars) x samples(128)` and then output the next batch of size `maxlen x lenght(chars) x samples` until the whole text file is read in and then go to the next text file...

The output for now is an error:

```
 Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (112512, 40, 43) for Tensor 'lstm_layer_input_1:0', which has shape '(128, 40, 43)'
```

hope I have explained it good enough to understand. I think I have to input some kind of for loop to iterate over the sample length but I have no Idea how to include this into the gen. function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented an for loop which is returning now batches of size 128:

Changed Code:

```
data_files_generator <- function(train_set) {

  files <- train_set
  next_file <- 0

  function() {

    # move to the next file (note the <<- assignment operator)
    next_file <<- next_file + 1

    # if we've exhausted all of the files then start again at the
    # beginning of the list (keras generators need to yield
    # data infinitely -- termination is controlled by the epochs
    # and steps_per_epoch arguments to fit_generator())
    if (next_file > length(files))
    {next_file <<- 1}

    # determine the file name
    file <- files[[next_file]]

    text <- read_lines(paste(data_dir, file, sep = "" )) %>%
      str_to_lower() %>%
      str_c(collapse = "\n") %>%
      removeNumbers() %>%
      tokenize_characters(strip_non_alphanum = FALSE, simplify = TRUE)

    text <- text[text %in% chars]

    dataset <- map(
      seq(1, length(text) - maxlen - 1, by = 3), 
      ~list(sentece = text[.x:(.x + maxlen - 1)], next_char = text[.x + maxlen])
    )

    dataset <- transpose(dataset)

    # Vectorization
    x <- array(0, dim = c(length(dataset$sentece), maxlen, length(chars)))
    y <- array(0, dim = c(length(dataset$sentece), length(chars)))

    for(i in 1:length(dataset$sentece)){

      x[i,,] <- sapply(chars, function(x){
        as.integer(x == dataset$sentece[[i]])
      })

      y[i,] <- as.integer(chars == dataset$next_char[[i]])

    }
    rounded_dim <- floor(dim(x)[1]/mini_batch_size)
    match_size_to_batch <- 128 * rounded_dim

    x <- x[1:match_size_to_batch, 1:maxlen, 1:length(chars)]
    y <- y_val[1:match_size_to_batch, 1:length(chars)]

    #Edit:
    span_start <-1
    for (iter in 1:rounded_dim){
     i <- iter * 128
     span_end <- iter * 128
     x <- x[span_start:span_end, 1:maxlen, 1:length(chars)]
     y <- y[span_start:span_end, 1:length(chars)]
     span_start <- i
     return(list(x, y))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you still getting the error? I think you also need `span_start <- i + 1` and make sure `span_end` doesn't go beyond the length in the file.

Comment: no error :) why would I need the + 1? I think it is alright. Thx anyway

Comment: Your span will look like this 1:128, then 128:256, then 256:384, and so on, so some samples will appear twice in separate batches. It probably doesn't make a big difference, but it is something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error, you're trying to feed in an object of shape `(112512, 40, 43)` but your LSTM layer is expecting an object of shape `(128, 40, 43)`. There seems to be some missing code, but when you're defining the input layer, are you fixing the batch size? I've had luck with defining my input layer as:

```
l_input = Input(shape = (None, num_features), name = 'input_layer')
```

I suspect the error is due to these lines of code:

```
rounded_dim <- floor(dim(x)[1]/mini_batch_size)
match_size_to_batch <- 128 * rounded_dim
```

This gives you a batch size much larger than 128. From the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/), the input shape should be `(batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`. The batch sizes need not be the same throughout an entire epic, but for a batch they all need to have the same number of `timesteps` (which it looks like you handle with `maxlen`).

Comment: That is right and this was my question. I wanted to change the code in such a way to get batches of size 128. I think I have managed to do it but I am not sure if the whole text will be returned or only the last batch. I will edit my code in the question.